# Replace "," with "." in a SQL query in Excel

Tags: sql, excel, replace

I have a column of numbers with different decimal symbols: the new observations have "." and the old observations have ",". I want them all to have a decimal point as delimiter.
When using `REPLACE(Column1, ",", ".")`, I get a correct result in cells where a decimal coma used to be, but an empty cell is returned for observations that had a decimal point previously.

| what I have | what I want | what I get |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2.9 | 2.9 |  |
| 3,1 | 3.1 | 3.1 |

How do I get to see a decimal point for all observations?
UPD: I create a query in my Excel workbook to import an xls from a web source. Excel imports a table from an xls file from the web. By default, the query for the table is SELECT * from Workbook. As I want to manipulate the data, I modify the OLE DB Query with Command Type "SQL" associated with the table. 
Thank you in advance.

**UPD 2**
The problem was that the first observation was a float. When converted to varchar, `REPLACE()` works perfectly well.

Comment: I'm confused.  Is Excel the data source or the query tool?

Comment: What type of SQL are you working with?

Comment: What steps do I need to take to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I import an xls file to Excel and then manipulate it using an SQL-type query within the workbook

Comment: "an SQL-type query"  Please describe the process, including the names of the components that are being used at each step.

Comment: **[EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73747425/edit)** your question to add this new information. Thanks.

Comment: I was going to correct your process text to make it read more like a step-by-step process, but I'm still confused.  Are you importing a .xls file, or are you querying a .xls file using SQL in an OLEDB connection?

Comment: Can you provide sample file names so we can reproduce the problem?  If the file you are accessing is private, you may need to find a sample excel data set online.

Comment: I'm still confused.  Where is the "import" command in Excel?  I don't see it.  Do you mean "Open"?

Comment: And before I just go downloading random stuff... how big is that document?

Comment: It doesn't matter.  The site doesn't respond.  Good luck.

Comment: Just do it like this:     `REPLACE(Column1, ',', '.')`

Answer (score 0):

Replace double quotes with single quotes. Like this:

```
REPLACE(Column1, ',', '.')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it yields the same result